# Get session of current user on trigger

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

I built a trigger on SQL Server to track delete's and update's on tables. But `CURRENT_USER` variable is returning as `dbo` and not the user I'm logging through sql client (C# interface program). I'm using Windows Authentication method (SSPI) with Active Directory users permissions.
So the objetive is like this:

```
create trigger fatura_historico_deleted
on Fatura
for delete
as
begin
    declare
        @id_fa int,
        @cod_fa nvarchar(100),
        @now datetime,
        @id_empr int,
        @data date,
        @preco money,
        @tipo nvarchar(50),
        @utilizador varchar(100),
        @ação varchar(30);
    SELECT
        @id_fa=id_fatura,
        @cod_fa=cod_fatura,
        @id_empr=id_empresa,
        @data = Data,
        @preco = Preço,
        @tipo = Tipo,
        @now=GETDATE(),
        @utilizador=CURRENT_USER, --THIS IS RETURNING 'dbo'
        @ação='Eliminado'
    FROM
        deleted
    insert into Fatura_Histórico(
        id_fatura,
        cod_fatura,
        id_empresa,
        Data,
        Preço,
        Tipo,
        Data_Registo,
        Utilizador,
        Ação
    ) values(
        @id_fa,
        @cod_fa,
        @id_empr,
        @data,
        @preco,
        @tipo,
        @now,
        @utilizador,
        @ação
    );
end
```

Is there anyway to get user who deleted or updated or who triggered this trigger?

Comment: select `SESSION_USER` and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31831524

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try    [**SYSTEM_USER**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179930.aspx), it works for me

Answer (score 3):

If you are a `dbo`, `CURRENT_USER` will always return `dbo`. If you are in an `execute as` context, then it will `suser_name()` and `system_user` will return the user you are impersonating.

Use `original_login()` to return the actual user.

```
use tempdb;
go
SELECT CURRENT_USER, system_user, suser_name(), original_login();
GO
EXECUTE AS USER = 'guest';
GO
SELECT CURRENT_USER, system_user, suser_name(), original_login();
GO
REVERT;
GO
SELECT CURRENT_USER, system_user, suser_name(), original_login();
GO
```